# Apache2 + multiple domains, same IP

Tags: apache2

I would like to host using Apache2 and I need to know how I can have two different domains pointing to the same static IP but different websites, so for example I could have bill.com and bob.com. 
They are both hosted on the same server, same ports but are different websites,  how could I go about doing this?

Edit: adding site specific `etc/apache2/sites-available/` files:

the test.conf:

```
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

ServerName www.turingwebs.tk 
ServerAlias turingwebs.tk

ServerAdmin webmaster@turingwebs.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And now the actual one I am using:

```
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

ServerName turingweb.co.uk

ServerAdmin webmaster@turingweb.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: You have to add additional VirtualHost entries for each site, defining individual docroots, etc.

Comment: Yes i have that, but when i point domains to the same IP they both go to the same webpage

Comment: Then please add your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bill.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bob.conf` and ... to your question. you did `sudo a2ensite bob`, right? See also [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

Comment: These were just an example - my real world .conf file looks like this, the .tk is for testing but the other one is real.

Comment: You still need to wrap that stuff within `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>` tags.

Comment: Yes i have done that, i just need to know how to have 2 domains running of same server and IP - but they are completely different websites.

Comment: So you are saying that www.turingwebs.tk does not go to the proper DocumentRoot at `/var/www/test/`?

Comment: It is unclear to me why you have the RewriteRules or why you have uncommented the vim: line

Comment: this is just because, when i copied the .conf file in it uncommented it

Comment: and www.turingwebs.tk went to the www.turingweb.co.uk page

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

### Easy way:

First, copy your `000-default.conf` file to two new .conf files:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf site1.conf
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf site2.conf
```

Edit each of these files, changing the `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` and `DocumentRoot` directives according to which URLs should redirect to which directory.

Now, just enable the sites and reload them:

```
sudo a2ensite site1 site2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Want proof that it's working? This is exactly what I did for my crazy cluster of sites. You can confirm with:

```
dig +short www.techyteen.tk
dig +short www.brownvpn.tk
dig +short www.browntech.tk
dig +short www.comic-cult.tk
dig +short www.nelida.tk
```

All domains point to the same IP, as seen by the output of `dig`. However, visit those pages in your browser, and you will see very different things. (However, don't criticize that last one. The guy really wanted to impress his girlfriend with it :P)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**